# Config .htaccess in which Laravel are subdirectory for Laravel 8

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-8

I Set my Laravel which handle the mobile API in the subdirectory of the main Web File.

So this how I setup, Directory look like

- webserver

  - mobile-api(laravel File)

    - public_html (Current System web File, index.php)

      - mobile (Contain index.php and .htaccess, for laravel)

So my issue is I try to execute the laravel api, when I put the .htacess, it does not work get 404 Error

Already enable the .htacess rewrite rules, below is the code that I used

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    
    
</IfModule>
```

**Update 16 July 9.44 8+GMT**

mobile (Contain index.php and .htaccess, for laravel) <- folder that act as public for laravel, which  is located in subdirectory of my main public_html

**Update 17 July 00.00 8+GMT**

Below show the Folder Directory and the contain for mobile, which in public_html

[image: The bottom is the file for mobile(which act as public for laravel)]

Answer (score 0):

to avoid htaccess problem,
add .htaccess and index.php inside public folder for laravel app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

in the directory laravel app you should add .htaccess to redirect the request to go to public folder, you can use this htaccess like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# That was ONLY to protect you from 500 errors
# if your server did not have mod_rewrite enabled

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# NOT needed unless you're using mod_alias to redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
# Direct all requests to /public folder

</IfModule>
```

could you tell us, what is your host/cpanel?

Comment: sorry, I did some update, the folder mobile is where I put my .htaccess and index.php, I am not sure about the hosting, as the hosting are handle by other team, I just can access the Folder in which I can replace and add the file.

Comment: could you update the question and add more details about the folder structure screenshot will be better

Comment: i did some update, by add the directory image

Comment: why you change laravel directory like this ?

Comment: I am trying to keep the previous, which the current Custom Framework are handling the Current Web project, So basically I plan to make the Laravel to handle all the API

Comment: i mean the folder structure break laravel default structure. all request move to public folder.

Comment: I did rename mobile into public

Comment: yes, not good practice to change laravel structure like this

Comment: I doing this Cause I want to keep the previous coding web file which use the custom framework. I need to make the mobile APIs, so I am trying to use laravel